# IReport: Error filling print... Error evaluating expression when use divide

Tags: jasper-reports, bigdecimal

I'm facing a problem when in Expression Editor use the divide function. I need to divide to fields (both are BigDecimal) so in Expression Editor write:

`$F{Field_A}.divide($F{Field_B})` and i'm getting the error below

`Error filling print... Error evaluating expression`

I tried to divide Field_A with Field_A (obviously the result is 1) and I didn't get an error. I'm thinking, the problem is the decimal part because Field_A has value 374 and Field_B, 365 so the result is 1.0246.

Comment: Did you check that both fields are initialized? You should add check for null and add reaction

Comment: @AlexK only during executing (preview). Do you mean to enter if-else for checking null or 0 values of fields?

Comment: `Do you mean to enter if-else for checking null or 0 values of fields?` - Yes, exactly

Comment: I get the same error when I use numbers (not fields or variables) like `(new BigDecimal("374")).divide(new BigDecimal("365"))`. I also tried check for null or zeros but unsuccessfully.

Comment: You should post small *jrxml* to reproduce the problem (with constants, for example)

Comment: You can find a sample .jrxml in the follow link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oy3j925vkkh2pii/test_stack.jrxml?dl=0